# Make Gboard default keyboard

Tags: keyboard, google

I'm new to using iOS with regularity. (Employer-issued phone is an iPhone 7.)

I can't stand the built-in keyboard. I've installed Gboard, but I can't figure out how to get it to come up.

When I press the globe on the default keyboard I don't get Gboard as an option. In any event, I'd like Gboard to come up as my new default rather than having to choose it each time (which I currently can't do anyway).

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Settings → General → Keyboard → Keyboards.
2. Choose Add New Keyboard… and select Gboard under Third-party keyboards.

   [image]
3. To set Gboard as default, tap Edit, then drag Gboard to the top of the list.

Comment: Did that already. I will uninstall and re-install and try again.

Comment: @ale Perhaps add the steps you've tried to your question, with some screenshots?

Comment: Is it me, or am I locked in to the default keyboard for Mail? I knew I would for passwords, but figured Mail would let me change. Slack and SMS work just fine.